# I am trying to understand react useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Can anyone please explain how react useEffect hook is working as `ComponentWillUnmount` here. Also how the loading state is handled using firebase `onAuthStateChanged`?

```js
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (user) => {
    setCurrentUser(user);
    setLoading(true);
  });
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Comment: Function returned from the callback function of `useEffect` hook is known as a _cleanup_ function which runs: 1. Before executing the `useEffect` again. 2. Before the component unmounts (just like `componentWillUnmount`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`useEffect` will take the function that you return and run it eventually when your component is unmounted. This is indeed the similar to how `ComponentWillUnmount` works. If you don't want any action on unmount just don't return anything in your `useEffect`.

You can read more about it in the [React effect hooks documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#example-using-hooks-1).